# Realm - Add a object to a list inside an other object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have this class:

```
class IndiClass: Object {
    dynamic var MediIndiGrpId = 0
    dynamic var MediIndiGrpName = ""
    let Medis = List<MediClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "MediIndiGrpId"
    }
}
```

I want to add now a MediClass object to the list.
This code shows how I get the object and how I try to add a MediClass object:

```
//Get a MediClass Object
let medi = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(MediClass.self, key: 1)
// Get the IndiClass Object
let indi = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(IndiClass.self, key: 1)
// Try to add the MediClass Object to the IndiClass Object:
indi!.Medis.append(medi!)
```

The last line stops the app and in the console it shows me:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't mutate a persisted array outside of a write transaction.'

Answer (score 5):

As the error message mentions, mutation of a persisted object must occur within a write transaction:

```
// Get a MediClass Object
let medi = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(MediClass.self, key: 1)
// Get the IndiClass Object
let indi = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(IndiClass.self, key: 1)

try! realm.write {
    // Try to add the MediClass Object to the IndiClass Object:
    indi!.Medis.append(medi!)
}
```